# Get object context in angularJs filter method?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter, angularjs-factory

I'm completely stumped.  I'm not understanding why I'm getting the parent scope on the object in my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KdAiTi?p=preview) (Line 51).

As far as I can tell, it looks like Angular must be calling .call() or .apply() on the filter, setting it's context to the current $scope or something.  But that just seems odd, why not just call the method and leave the context alone?

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
.controller('MyCtl', function(
  $scope,
  WidgetsService
){
  WidgetsService.getWidgets().then(function(widgets){
    $scope.entireWidgetsList = widgets;
  });

})
.directive('widgetsFilteredList', function(
  WidgetsService
){
  return{
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      filter: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'widgets-filtered-list.directive.html',
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.typeAheadModel = null;
      $scope.widgetsResults = null;
      $scope.$watch(function(){
        return ($scope.typeAheadModel) ? $scope.typeAheadModel : null;
      }, function(newV, oldV){
        if(newV && newV != oldV){
          var reqPromise = WidgetsService.getWidgets();

          reqPromise.then(function(widgets){
            $scope.widgetsResults = widgets;
          }, angular.noop);
        }
      });
    }
  };
})
.factory('WidgetFactory', function(){
  function Widget(data){
    var defaultStructure = {
      id: null,
      color: null,
      cogs: []
    };

    _.merge(this, defaultStructure, data);
  }

  Widget.prototype.widgetFilter = function(){
    var self = this;
    return function(widget){
      console.log(self); //How the heck do I get this to give me the proper context??
      //compare 'widget' this the widget in context for return value.  Like:
      // return !!!(widget.id === self.id);  //Would remove the context widget from the result set;
      return true;
    }
  };

  var create = function(data){
    return new Widget(data);
  };

  return {
    create: create
  };
})
.service('WidgetsService', function(
  WidgetFactory,
  $q,
  $timeout
){
  return {
    getWidgets: function(){
      var def = $q.defer();

      $timeout(function(){
          var widgetResults = [
            WidgetFactory.create({
              id:1,
              color: 'red',
              cogs: []
            }),
            WidgetFactory.create({
              id:2,
              color: 'blue',
              cogs: [1, 2]
            }),
            WidgetFactory.create({
              id:3,
              color: 'green',
              cogs: []
            }),
            WidgetFactory.create({
              id:4,
              color: 'yellow',
              cogs: []
            })
          ];

          def.resolve(widgetResults);
      }, 500);

      return def.promise;
    }  
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing your widgetFilter as a closure, essentially to $scope, thats why you see the console.log(self) output being the $scope object. Instead put the widgetfilter function inside the factory like this:

```
.factory('WidgetFactory', function(){
  function Widget(data){
    var defaultStructure = {
      id: null,
      color: null,
      cogs: []
    };

    var self=this
    this.widgetFilter=function(){
      console.log(self)
    }

    _.merge(this, defaultStructure, data);
  }
```

Comment: Looks like your breadcrumb worked out.  But you forgot to return the closure for the filter to utilize.

I've updated the plunker and it now works.

Thanks!